# Select elements between A and B efficiently

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, selector

I have a table with a lot of td's. What would be the most efficient way to select selection 1 to selection 2 and everything in-between?

On selection 1 i give the selected td an id and on selection 2 i give that selection another id in order to later on look for those id's.

Current code:

```
// small helpers
function _for(e,f) { var i, len=e.length; for(i=0;i<len;i++){ f(e[i]); }}
function _id(e) { return document.getElementById(e); }

// VARs
var main = _id('monthTables'),
    td = main.querySelectorAll('td'),
    go = false,
    stop = false,
    i = 0,
    s1i = 0,
    s2i = 999;

// Loop throught td's
_for(td, function(e){

    if( e.id == 'sel1' ) { go = 1; s1i = i; }
    if( e.id == 'sel2' ) { stop = 1; s2i = i; }

    if( s1i < s2i && go ) {
        if(go) { e.classList.add('range'); }
    }

    if( stop ) { go = 0; }

}) // end loop
```

---

**Live example (select two dates):**
http://cdn.rawgit.com/tommiehansen/lightRange/master/test.html

Comment: Just store results in an array. You can also refactor your helper so it would be possible to `return` early from your `_for` function - you don't really need to do anything with elements after you found end marker.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov `main.querySelectorAll('td')` is an array. A problem with modifying the `_for` -helper is that it is a generic function that is used throughout the code for different purposes. You're correct that it's unessecary to continue looping when all conditions have been met as well. A `if( !stop ) { /* CODE */ }` in the beginning of the loop would solve some of that however if one select td 531 the loop still have to loop through 531 elements and check all conditions on those.

Comment: @Tommie, no, it is a `NodeList` - it doesn't have all the methods of array, so you may want to copy elements to real array if you need them when you return to this data in future. As for `_for` function - maybe you need another one for this case if you're concerned with performance. You don't really need to fit all task to one "universal" tool.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Yes -- of course, you're right. :) What i'm thinking is to not select the td's upon initialization but rather store that when the tables themself are created or upon initializing the date range picker. But i still need the nodelist in order to add stuff to them else i must create an array and compare that array to array #1 etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is good in my opinion, maybe you could add few optimizations (like stopping the loop when found the second selected id )

Example for the loop:

```
function _for(e,f) { 
  var i, len=e.length; 
  for(i=0;i<len;i++){ if(f(e[i]) === false) break; }
}
```

so it will break when the function f returns `false`

```
// Loop throught td's
_for(td, function(e){

    //...

    if( stop ) return false;

}) // end loop
```

Also i suggest you to use `getElementsByTagName` instead of `querySelectorAll` if you want a bit more [performance](https://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname) ..but maybe that's an evil micro optimization

An other optimization would be to start looping from the first selected td, maybe [storing the index](http://w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp) when you select the td and using that value in that code you posted as initial index

Comment: Thank you. This was a nice and concicse way of solving the 'stopping the loop'. However it doesn't seem to work since `f(e[i])` isn't 'truthy' per default. But a modified loop would probably work.

getElementsByTagName is a micro-optimization but in this case it can make somewhat of a difference. At desktop these sort of things isn't a a real problem so it depends on how much better `getElementsByTagName` is on weak devices (mobile phones etc)

Comment: you're right sorry, i've changed the condition inside the _for function , now it will work. An other optimization would be to start looping from the first selected td, maybe storing the index when you select the td and using that value in that code you posted as initial index http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp

Comment: Yes it did but with the penalty of always checking for that condition, but that penalty does more good then bad so it's much better then it is bad.

cellIndex doesn't work on multiple tables? Check the linked demo at http://cdn.rawgit.com/tommiehansen/lightRange/master/test.html  What i may opt for is to cache the array before user actually inits something in order to not have that overhead when the user performs actions. If you check the demo you'll also see that the selection is needed for `:hover` as well.

Comment: Also opted for `e.className += ' range';` since that is twice as fast (Crome 47) as `classList.add` and 'add' isn't really needed in that specific case.

Comment: I made a jsperf test to check the impact on performance of that condition inside the _for function http://jsperf.com/test5211218496

Comment: That's odd. I don't get how checking for something would be more performant than not.

Comment: It surprised me too.  Maybe I typed wrong something or the site is calculating it wrong. ...Else would be nice if someone more into javascript could explain this unexpected result

Comment: I'm marking your answer as the best one since it was more helpful.